# Using Tshark commands How to produce "DHCP option 82" output in a user readable form (ASCII))

Tags: tshark

[I have DHCP option 82 value in pcap file ->click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdhdW.png)

[I am using the below tshark commmand to fetch option 82 value->click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHUXo.png)

I want the option 82 output to be printed in ASCII format instead of binary and hexadecimal format.

Comment: Instead of images, which are difficult to copy/paste, could you add the command to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xxd` to convert tshark's hexadecimal output into ASCII (after extracting the first column using `awk`):

```
$ echo "50:45:45:52 100 00:01" | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p
PEER
```